# nao control rate

Tags: nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I reduce nao control rate in ros??

I use ros publisher "/cmd_vel"

like this,

ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Publisher cmd_pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/cmd_vel", 1000);

while (ros::ok())
{

cmd_pub(msg);
ros::getGlobalCallbackQueue()->callAvailable(ros::WallDuration(0.5));

}

so, my control rate is 0.5 seconds.

if I control nao for each 0.4 or 0.3 or less, nao ignore some order.

How can I reduce this interval? I already use spin() or spinOnce(), else(changing function).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/88256/nao-control-rate/) by [dlxhrl](https://answers.ros.org/users/7521/dlxhrl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could use ros::Rate()

```
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Publisher cmd_pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::twist>("/cmd_vel", 1000);
ros::Rate loop_rate(2);

while (ros::ok()) {
    cmd_pub.publish(msg);
    loop_rate.sleep();
}
```

The "loop_rate" input is a frequency in Hertz so you can adjust that as needed. See [this tutorial for more details](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29).

---

Originally posted by [jdorich](https://answers.ros.org/users/7496/jdorich/) with karma: 211 on 2013-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dlxhrl](https://answers.ros.org/users/7521/dlxhrl/) on 2013-10-16**:
Thank you for your response. OK, i'll try
but It doesn't matter?? there are no spin() or spinOnce()?? or callbackqueue?

**Comment by [jdorich](https://answers.ros.org/users/7496/jdorich/) on 2013-10-16**:
you only need to use the spin() or spinOnce() if you have subscribed to a topic. The loop_rate.sleep() performs the delay you require in this situation.